# Install font button grayed out

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts

I'm trying to install Courier font (not Courier New) on Windows 7/8, but even though on Windows Control Panel the font is marked as installable, the install button is grayed out, even disabling Uac.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the font is marked as installable"? Some screenshots would be nice.

Comment: What happens when you right click on the font file?

Comment: You should see what I'm describing here going on the font section of windows control panel. The font is marked as installable means that in the far right of the font info there is a label with written that it's possible to install, but it's not installed.

Comment: If I right click on the font itself, a demo windows with some text pops up, with the install button grayed out.